Switching off when a percentage of the peak value has been reached in LTspice
Recently, I asked a question about turning on a switch when the current crosses through zero and switches off when a 80% peak value has been reached. For example, I simulated a sinus signal and a switch should be turned on into the these phases, see figure below & link. Link to: Cycle off a voltage at a specific amplitude height [revised].


Russell McMahon described a solution to use a micro-controller for the detection off the 80% value when the input waveform could vary in amplitude.
However, I cannot make any progress with the answer given due to my inexperience in LTspice/ electricl engineering (biomedical engineer). Therefore, I would like a broader explanation about capturing this 80% value to cycle off the switch in LTspice.
I have checked the following post if it would be appropiate to ask the question and I thought it would be. If you have another idea, please let me now. If an answerer does not sufficiently clarify their answer, should I post a new question about that answer?

What does this mean --> switching on a model

I meant turn on the switch, so only in this area the Pinsp voltage source should be applied to the circuit.

The goal isn't clearly stated, but I'll take a guess:

The output is the middle graph. 
More needs to be added to ensure the proper startup condition for an actual circuit as you could end up with an inverted response. Perhaps, reset the flip-flop at some point when the input is negative.

The goal is to apply a voltage Pinsp to the circuit at the time points of the red block pulses. Therefore, I had to identify those points. I guess I can now directly apply the voltage of Q2 to the circuit instead of the switch SW_1 & Pinsp
